# Identical contract on BNB chain fails, working on ETH

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance, erc20

I have two contracts of identical ERC20 code, but on BNB chain the functions fail, such as allowance, and on Ethereum they are fine.

I can't seem to understand why, I've never seen this happen before. I tested on Fantom testnet as well, and it also fails.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe95fc92e1ae8b46e83fc970f9a5f28c9439839ff#readContract

https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x6f74C965Fe9A27d3A84c88c83F4700351b0c2e8d#readContract

Allowance returns `uint256 :  Error: Wrong response id "0" (expected: "8") in {"jsonrpc":"2.0"` on BNB chain

And passes on ETH

Answer (score 1):

The allowance is different for every chain.

You need to call the `approve` function on each chain where you want to give allowance.

Comment: I did an approval on BNB for the owner, and still get the error when running a read on allowance. `uint256 :  Error: Wrong response id "0" (expected: "2") in {"jsonrpc":"2.0"`

ETH does not need to run an approval.